# Oracle text CONTAINS and LIKE : different results

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, oracle-text

There are two problems:

- different results while using `LIKE` and `CONTAINS`
- serious lack of speed while searching single character with `CONTAINS`

I'm trying to get rid of searching with `LIKE` due to performance reasons but oracle text doesn't work properly for me.

I'm not sure if it's important but CLOB's contains mostly russian text. In my mind it doesn't matter because of `CONTAINS` search is not using vocabularies and lexical elements analysing.

Total amount of rows in table : 215577

```
-- index creation
create index schema_name.idx_01 on schema_name.t_searchable_table(clob_value)
  indextype is ctxsys.context 
  parameters ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE sync (on commit)');

-- index sync
begin
  ctx_ddl.sync_index('SCHEMA_NAME.IDX_01');
end;
```

As far as I see index successfully refreshed with commit but I can't find any visual approval of this.

Here are some queries I tried, results of `LIKE` search are for performance and amount comparison. I'm testing performance with inserting data into table (query time is stable enough).

```
--- String search
-- original "not tuned" query with like '%%'
-- 116643 rows inserted in 8,653 seconds
insert into schema_name.t_search_results t
  (session_id, entity_id)
  select 'a', a.entity_id
   from schema_name.t_searchable_table a
  where lower(a.clob_value) like '%про%';

-- this is not correct query due to documentation but it's fast and sql%rowcount is same
-- 116643 rows inserted in 2,959 seconds
insert into schema_name.t_search_results t
  (session_id, entity_id)
  select 'a', a.entity_id
    from schema_name.t_searchable_table a
   where contains(a.clob_value, '%про%',1 ) > 0;

-- correct query due to oracle docs but absolutely incorrect amount
-- 11 rows inserted in 0,081 seconds
insert into schema_name.t_search_results t
  (session_id, entity_id)
  select 'a', a.entity_id
    from schema_name.t_searchable_table a
   where contains(a.clob_value, 'про',1 ) > 0;

--- Number search
-- original "not tuned" query with like '%%'
-- 121918 rows inserted in 8,045 seconds
insert into schema_name.t_search_results t
  (session_id, entity_id)
  select 'a', a.entity_id
   from schema_name.t_searchable_table a
  where lower(a.clob_value) like '%1%';

-- Little differs by amount but fast. 
-- 117228 rows inserted in 2,065 seconds
insert into schema_name.t_search_results t
  (session_id, entity_id)
  select 'a', a.entity_id
    from schema_name.t_searchable_table a
   where contains(a.clob_value, '1',1 ) > 0;

-- Lost one row here (not sure why) but SUPERSLOW
-- 121917 rows inserted in 97,760 seconds
insert into schema_name.t_search_results t
  (session_id, entity_id)
  select 'a', a.entity_id
    from schema_name.t_searchable_table a
   where contains(a.clob_value, '%1%',1 ) > 0;


-- Single character
-- original "not tuned" query with like '%%'
-- 124095 rows inserted in 9,112 seconds
insert into schema_name.t_search_results t
  (session_id, entity_id)
  select 'a', a.entity_id
   from schema_name.t_searchable_table a
  where lower(a.clob_value) like '%а%';

-- Incorrect syntax, amount is good, performance is awful
-- 124095 rows inserted in 94,927 seconds
insert into schema_name.t_search_results t
  (session_id, entity_id)
  select 'a', a.entity_id
    from schema_name.t_searchable_table a
   where contains(a.clob_value, '%а%',1 ) > 0;

-- correct syntax, fast and smooth (and almost double rows lost)
-- 60345 rows inserted in 1,215 seconds
insert into schema_name.t_search_results t
  (session_id, entity_id)
  select 'a', a.entity_id
    from schema_name.t_searchable_table a
   where contains(a.clob_value, 'а',1 ) > 0;
```

Comment: I figured out that ```contains(a.clob_value, 'про',1 ) > 0;``` worked "improper" for me because it searched only whole words. That's why using ```%%``` gave proper results.

Comment: So the only thing left is : "how should I rebuild index to operate pieces of words sized for example of 3 characters".

Answer (score 0):

You can try rebuilding using a [BASIC_WORDLIST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cdatadic.htm#CCREF2023) and specifying `TRUE` for the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` attribute.

This should hopefully improve performance when doing '%npo%' wildcard searches.

You can use this [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cdatadic.htm#GUID-BCB52EAF-7327-4002-B3D5-40432A8C2F81) preference example as a guideline and adjust accordingly to your needs.